# Concatenação de String em um diretorio

Tags: php

Bom pessoa, quero concatenar uma string, colocar ela no final do diretorio, o que vai ser meu caminho onde salvo as imagens, cada usuario tem sua pasta no servidor. Não estou conseguindo concatenar devido as barras que no explorer é ao contrario,se alguem puder me ajudar fico grato!

```
 <?php
$nomepasta = "morto";
$base = $_REQUEST['image'];
$filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];
$binary = base64_decode($base);
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
$file = fopen(('UploadFotos/'.$nomepasta).$filename, 'wb');
$teste = 'UploadFotos\'.$nomepasta;
fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);
echo $teste;
```

Comment: Segundo o [php](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.request.php) a informação `$_FILE` foi removida do `$_REQUEST` desde a versão `4.3.0`, se está usando uma versão superior, mude para `$_FILE`. Quanto a barra, tente `"/UploadFotos/{$nomepasta}"` ou `//'` no lugar de `/'`.

Comment: O problema é que a imagem está salvando fora da pasta desejada, ta salvando na raiz /UploadFotos/, quando deveria salvar dentro de uma pastas UploadFotos/meuemail@grmail.com. Por isso acho que e questão de apas, pois fiz o teste colocando o email direto no codigo e funcionou!

Answer (score 1):

O PHP já tem constantes apropriadas para retornar as barras do OS, e outras coisas relacionadas ao *filesystem*.

Para retornar as barras, a constante usada é:

```
DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
$path = 'uploadfotos'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'nomepasta';
```

ou:

```
$path = join( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array( 'raiz', 'uploadfotos', 'nomepasta' ) );
```

Fazendo desta forma, o mesmo código vai funcionar corretamente independente do sistema operacional (desde que o caminho esteja correto, claro).

Outra vantagem é que evita que as barras sejam entendidas como caracteres de escape.

Caso os caminhos venham de um DB, você pode gravá-los sempre com barra normal e usar um replace:

```
$path = str_replace( '/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $caminho_vindo_do_db );
```

Mais detalhes no manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/dir.constants.php

Comment: Boa pessoal ! Achei a resposta:  $file = fopen("UploadFotos/$nomepasta/".$filename, 'wb'); Vale pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Juliano estou analisando os seu código e concordo menção do William Novak, outra coisa barras antes de aspas funcionam como escape no php, veja os exemplos:

```
    <?php
    \\quando quer ter o resultado meu nome é "Antonio".
    echo 'meu nome é \"Antonio\"';
```

para que a barra seja incluida no texto deve se user da seguinte forma

```
    <?php
    echo 'menu nome é \"Antonio\\"';
    \\o resultado será meu nome é Antonio\
```

o escape funciona para informar que as aspas não estão incluídas no código.
tenta usar algo do tipo

```
    <?php
    $pasta_imagens = "diretorio_principal";
    $nomepasta = "/nome_da_pasta";
    //agora é possivel concatenar sem erros de scape ficando assim
    $file = fopen(($pasta_imagens.$nomepasta).$filename, 'wb');
```

Existem muitas formas diferentes de resolver tentei explicar de uma forma mais simples, mas já é possível ter uma ideia de como pode tentar solucionar.

Comment: $_REQUEST descontinuado? quando isso?

Comment: O problemae que o meu "nomepasta" é de uma variavel que vem do meu app, não sei se nao e isso o problema,